# How to calculate bit (and byte) width of an integer value range

Tags: c#

I had a situation where I needed to calculate the byte width of a value range, for the purpose of parsing bytes received on a serial communication link.  Using the width of the data type wouldn't be desirable, as I would end up with taking into account a lot of bytes never to be used.  In my case the value would be between 0 and 4095 (i.e. 12 bits or two bytes wide), but that wouldn't always be the case.  The maximum value could have been 255 (8 bits or one byte), or 100.000 for that matter (17 bits or three bytes).

**So how to calculate the bit / byte width of a value range?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**METHOD 1**

A solution for me was to use calculus, and invert the equation for calculating the max range:  `maxRange = 2^bitWidth;`

Which gives: `bitWidth = log10(maxRange) / log10(2);`

Or as [Damien_The_Unbeliever](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15498/damien-the-unbeliever) points out about `Math.Log()` overload: `bitWidth = log2(maxRange);`

And then round up to get to the closest bit, divide by 8 and round up again, to get the closest byte.

So a C# implementation becomes:

```
private int GetByteWidth(long maxValue)
{
    int bitLength = (int)Math.Ceiling(Math.Log(ValueRangeMaximum, 2));  // Finding 2^bitLength=ValueRangeMaximum
    int byteLength = (int)Math.Ceiling((double)bitLength / 8);  // Rounding up to nearest byte
    return byteLength;
}
```

A smaller method isolating the method for calculating the bit width (see section about calculations):

```
public static int CalculateBitWidthMethod1(int value)
{
    int bitWidth = (int)Math.Ceiling(Math.Log(value, 2));
    return bitWidth;
}
```

---

**METHOD 2**

A second method from the [web page](https://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html#IntegerLogObvious) that [Marc](https://stackoverflow.com/users/23354/marc-gravell) linked to:

```
public static int CalculateBitWidthMethod2(int value)
{
    int bitWidth = 1;
    while ((value >>= 1) > 0)
    {
        bitWidth++;
    }
    return bitWidth;
}
```

---

**CALCULATIONS**

I created a small console application for testing the isolated bit width calculation methods.  Source code: https://github.com/ohjohnsen/BitWidthCalculations

It calculates the bit width of the integer value `1000000` ten million times, and prints the elapsed time in milliseconds.

My results varies a bit, but the overall performance of the methods are as follows:

- Method 1: Approx. 810 ms.
- Method 2: Approx. 760 ms.

Comment: I didn't find the solution on SO, and had to dig quite a long time before finding a good and working solution.  So I'm just thinking it might be helpful for others.

Comment: `Math.Log` has an overload accepting the required base. No need to do base-conversion yourself.

Comment: Also, using `Round` is wrong. According to this, I can store 0-65537 in 2 bytes.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Hmm..  You're right.  Should be Math.Ceiling.  Thanks,

Comment: There are just 32 possible bit-widths (for `int`), can't you pre-calculate the limits and do a lookup? Any value between 128 and 255 (inclusive) will take 8 bits.

Answer (score 2):

The most efficient way of doing this is probably by using "lzcnt" - i.e. the "leading zero count". {Width minus lzcnt} tells you the number of *used* bits, and "lzcnt" is a CPU intrinsic.

This is available via:

1. [`BitOperations.LeadingZeroCount`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.numerics.bitoperations.leadingzerocount) (32 and 64-bit; uses CPU intrinsic with software fallback)
2. [`Lzcnt.LeadingZeroCount`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.intrinsics.x86.lzcnt.leadingzerocount) (32-bit; CPU intrinsic only)
3. [`Lzcnt.X64.LeadingZeroCount`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.intrinsics.x86.lzcnt.x64.leadingzerocount) (64-bit; CPU intrinsic only)

---

Outdated:

Unfortunately, unless you're using [experimental .NET Core code](https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/blob/master/src/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/Runtime/Intrinsics/X86/Lzcnt.cs) (currently [in "rc1"](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Runtime.Intrinsics.Experimental/4.5.0-rc1)), CPU intrinsics aren't readily available, but there are efficient algorithmic ways of doing it using a precomputed log table to avoid expensive math operations; see ["Find integer log base 2", here](https://graphics.stanford.edu/%7Eseander/bithacks.html)

Comment: Thanks a lot for the input.  You're right, rolling down from the MSb to first set bit would also be an easy way to get bit width.  Also interesting to see other methods if efficiency is a factor.

Comment: @Oystein and if you have "lzcnt" available (i.e. the new "intrinsics" package, when it ships), it is pretty much a no-brainer; with direct CPU intrinsic support, it is *blindingly* fast; this is Spring 2007 technology

Comment: @Oystein interesting: I hadn't seen it before, but there's also [bsr](https://software.intel.com/sites/landingpage/IntrinsicsGuide/#text=bsr&expand=393,396), which does *exactly* what you're asking (no need to subtract from width) - and is x86 / ARM / x64; it might be a *compiler* intrinsic rather than a *CPU* intrinsic, though

Comment: Very interesting about the intrinsic commands.  Haven't heard about those before..

Comment: This is available in the `System.Numerics` namespace with the `BitOperations.LeadingZeroCount(uint value)` method.

Comment: @RobertMassa it wasn't at the time :) updated, thanks